# C Bidirectional Client Server Example

Tags: c, sockets, bidirectional

I am fairly new to sockets and understand the point of a server client relationship. I was just wondering if there is some sort of way for the client to return a response to the server in c.

Im thinking, should I use the same socket connection, or create another file descriptor within my client to send it to my server. Also is there a better way to implement this?

The main goal is to have bidirectional communication.

I have provided my example code below:

Server:

```
void connection(char* sentMessage){
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks; 

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

listen(listenfd, 10); 

while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

    ticks = time(NULL);
    snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.90s\r\n", sentMessage);
    write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 
    printf("Snoopy Detected: %s", sendBuff);

    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);
 }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//construct a string to pass to the client
char* protocol = "eax:valuevlaue, ebx:asdjasdjasd, ecx:sadafw, edx:asdfsasd";

connection(protocol);
}
```

Client:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
char recvBuff[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
    return 1;
} 

memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
    return 1;
} 

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
    return 1;
} 

if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
   printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
   return 1;
} 

while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
{
    recvBuff[n] = 0;
    printf("Input: %s\n", recvBuff);
    //parse it into eax, and such

    char input[4][40];        
    char *ch;
    int i = 0;
    ch = strtok(recvBuff, ",");
    while (ch != NULL) {
        strcpy(input[i], ch);
        ch = strtok(NULL, " ,");
        i++;
    }

    //
    // After this, do what you'd like with the input from donor
    // And return the result back to the server
    //

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < 4 ; j++){
        printf("%s\n", input[j]);
    }
} 

if(n < 0)
{
    printf("\n Read error \n");
} 

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I did it!

So apparently, sockets are inherently bidirectional, so all I had to do is `write()` back to the `sockfd` and read it from the server side!